# How can I ban a program or application from using the microphone?

Tags: microphone

I would like to, for example, set my mic level to 0 for an specific program, but still be able to use it in other ones. How could I do that?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @Kulfy my ubuntu version is 19.10